# Google sheets: Returns "False" if the time is in the range from 23:00 to 05:00 (or from 11:00 PM to 05:00 AM)

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ifs

My formula should return **4 different** text values depending on what **time value** is in the cell.

Everything would work fine, **but** every time I try to make the formula look at the time from **23:00** to **05:00**, it always returns **False** or **#N/A** if in full formula. I tried in **12 hours format** but it works the same way.

```
=IFS(
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="05:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="10:59"),"SS",
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="11:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="16:59"),"AA",
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="17:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="22:59"),"MM",
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="23:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="04:59"),"LL")
```

Everything works **correctly** in this formula except for the **last line**. Instead of **LL**, **# N/A** returns. And I **don't understand** why this is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(C18, {
 0,              "LL"; 
 VALUE("5:00"),  "SS";
 VALUE("11:00"), "AA";
 VALUE("17:00"), "MM";
 VALUE("23:00"), "LL"}, 2, 1)
```

[image]

or:

```
=VLOOKUP(TIMEVALUE(C18), {
 TIMEVALUE("00:00"), "LL"; 
 TIMEVALUE("05:00"), "SS";
 TIMEVALUE("11:00"), "AA";
 TIMEVALUE("17:00"), "MM";
 TIMEVALUE("23:00"), "LL"}, 2, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Your second way works great! But I don't quite understand how. Didn't know that this formula can be used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer:

Since you are covering the **full** time range of the day, if the return value of the `IFS` is `NA` it means that there is no match. In this case, return `LL`:

```
=ifna(IFS(
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="05:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="10:59"),"SS",
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="11:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="16:59"),"AA",
AND(TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")>="17:00",TEXT(C18,"HH:MM")<="22:59"),"MM"),"LL")
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I will know about it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFS(
 (TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")>="05:00")*(TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")<="10:59"), "SS",
 (TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")>="11:00")*(TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")<="16:59"), "AA",
 (TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")>="17:00")*(TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")<="22:59"), "MM",
((TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")>="23:00")*(TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")<="23:59"))+
((TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")>="00:00")*(TEXT(C18, "HH:MM")<="04:59")), "LL")
```

[image]